# Recompiling goattracker2 on Windows 10

Tags: makefile, sdl, tracker, sid, recompile

I recently downloaded goattracker2 on Windows 10 and after making some changes to the source code, I need to recompile the program to test it.

I don't have any experience with recompiling.
I had a look at the documentation included in the readme-file:

> 8. Recompiling
>
> ---
>
> To recompile for Win32, you need the MinGW development environment,
> use the file src/makefile.win as makefile.
>
> To recompile for Linux, use src/makefile.
>
> In both cases you need the SDL development libraries in addition to
> the SDL runtime, see http://www.libsdl.org.
>
> Compile first the utilities (datafile & dat2inc) from the src/bme
> directory, and place them to your path.

This leaves me with several questions, like

- Which programs do I need to download
- How do I run or execute the makefile
- Where do I need to install the SDL libraries

If anyone has experience with recompiling goattracker, can they provide a step by step tutorial for how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get MinGW (I recommend 32bit version) and install.
2. Download and unpack the SDL Libraries from https://www.libsdl.org/ (depending on your version you might need [SDL 1.x](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php))
3. The SDL Libraries (the `*.a` files) have to be added in the lib directory of MinGW installation directory (this might be different from the lib dir of MinGW, see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243453/mingw-g-doesnt-find-headers-in-its-own-include-directory))
4. The header files from SDL (SDL2/ directory MinGW) have to be put where MinGW can find them (this might be different from the include dir of MinGW, see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243453/mingw-g-doesnt-find-headers-in-its-own-include-directory))
5. Go to the `src` directory of goattracker and type `make -f makefile.win`